How to make a dropdown menu visible even when it exceeds the browser's edge?
On LinkedIn, I noticed that their dropdown menu extends beyond the browser's edge but remains visible.
I initially thought it's impossible to render content outside the browser's visible area. I experimented with overflow and similar properties but couldn't achieve the desired effect.
Does anyone have a simple example (HTML + CSS) to demonstrate how this can be implemented?


"I experimented with overflow and similar properties but couldn't achieve the desired effect".  We can't help you figure out why your code did not work, if you do not show us your code.

that's just normal  behavior, you're expecting it to be special but it's not
